# Array Data Value not show in input box

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-3

Here input in **CodeIgniter** view.

`<input type="text" value="<?php echo $st_data->sp_qty ;?> >`

The `sp_qty` is coming from `database`

Here, the value is stored like as `"57"`

[image: Database Value]

But I need To show like this, Not to remove the `""` symbol. How can I display it into input value?

Comment: I solve this by own. Need to use.  `$sp_qty = json_decode($st_data->sp_qty );                      
echo $sp_qty;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo '"'.$st_data->sp_qty.'"' ;?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes around the value, like this:

```
<input type="text" value='<?php echo $st_data->sp_qty ;?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add quotes around your echo statement in two ways.

If you are allowed to use single quotes:

```
<input type="text" value='"<?= $st_data->sp_qty ?>"'>
```

Otherwise you can use HTML entities:

```
<input type="text" value="&quot;<?= $st_data->sp_qty ?>&quot;">
```